# CreateTextFile with a Colon in the path , no error is returned. Why?

Tags: powershell, createfile

This is what I tried (C:\temp really exists):

```
$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject 
$ts = $fso.CreateTextFile("c:\temp:AAAAA.txt")      
$ts.Close()
```

No error returned. The file is created somewhere (but not in c:\temp... if I put something inside, I can later read it) 
but I cannot find it.

Could anyone explain me why this code not produce an error & where the file gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't get an error is probably that the call succeeded!

When you call `CreateTextFile` and pass the file path `C:\temp:AAAAA.txt`, you're actually asking to create a file `C:\temp` with an alternate data stream (an `ADS`) named `AAAAA.txt`.

You can see for yourself with `Get-Item`:

```
PS C:\> Get-Item C:\temp -Stream AAAAA.txt

PSPath        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\temp:AAAAA.txt
PSParentPath  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\
PSChildName   : temp:AAAAA.txt
PSDrive       : C
PSProvider    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer : False
FileName      : C:\temp
Stream        : AAAAA.txt
Length        : 0
```

You can also read and write to alternate data streams (requires PowerShell version 5 or newer):

```
PS C:\> "Hello there!" |Set-Content C:\temp -Stream AAAAA.txt
PS C:\> Get-Content C:\temp -Stream AAAAA.txt
Hello there!
```

Please beware that [these data streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/b134f29a-6278-4f3f-904f-5e58a713d2c5) are intrinsic to NTFS and won't persist if you copy a file to a non-NTFS file system or upload them to a website for example.